# Delete specific items in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to delete cells in a UICollectionView, which have a certain ID. So the cell can be in the middle of the view.

To do so I remove the item from my cell array and also remove the indexPath. The indexPath has to be retrieved first. This is not possible!

Somehow the cells which are not visible / hidden (below the current view, have to be scrolled up) can not be deleted, as they turn out to be NIL.

How can I access a certain cell (with an ID) and delete it?

```
    let cellIdToFeedItem_ToDelete = [ String : FeedItem ]() // here are the item to be deleted
    var indexPathsToRemove        = [ IndexPath ]()
    var indexPathsAllActive       = [ IndexPath ]() // Will be filled below

    // --- retrieving all indexPaths
    if let nrSections = self.collectionView?.numberOfSections
    {
        for s in 0..<nrSections
        {
            if let v = self.collectionView?.numberOfItems( inSection: s )
            {
                for i in 0..<v
                {
                    let indexPathTMP = IndexPath( item: i, section: s )
                    indexPathsAllActive.append( indexPathTMP )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // --- delete the items with the same
    for indexPath in indexPathsAllActive
    {
        // #### FOR HIDDEN CELLS THIS IS 'NIL'
        let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem( at: indexPath ) as? FeedCollectionViewCell

        if let cellID = cell?.id
        {
            if let _ = cellIdToFeedItem_ToDelete[ cellID ]
            {
                if let index = feedItemsActive_.firstIndex( where: {
                    (i) -> Bool in
                    i.id == cellID
                } )
                {
                    feedItemsActive_.remove( at: index )
                    indexPathsToRemove.append( indexPath )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    self.collectionView?.deleteItems( at: indexPathsToRemove )
```

Comment: Why are you getting the cells? Cells are views, not your data. Iterate through your data model, not the cells.

Comment: I am getting the cells to get the ID. What should I iterate instead to find out I am deleting the right one?

Comment: As I said, iterate your data model. That's where the id came from originally.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the items from your datasource (indexPathsAllActive I assume?) then reload your collectionView to show the changes.

Without animation:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

With animations:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates{ }
```

Here's how you'd use performBatchUpdates with your code: (If you have one section)

```
collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
    var targetIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
    for ( cellID, _ ) in cellIdToFeedItem_ToDelete
    {
        if let index = feedItemsActive_.firstIndex( where: { $0.id == cellID } )
        {
            feedItemsActive_.remove( at: index )
            targetIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))
        }
    }
    collectionView?.deleteItems(at: targetIndexPaths]) 
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `reloadData()` is so harsh, `performBatchUpdates()` would result in better UX.

Comment: performBatchUpdated{ } crashes when I delete elements from my data model, but not the cells. This leads to my initial question. How do I get all the cells/indexpaths?

Comment: in ``performBatchUpdates``you need to update both dataSource and the collectionview

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but the initial questions is, how to. As I cannot get all collectionView items (indexPaths). Do you know how to get them? Hidden elements are not retrieved with my code. Neither with .indexPathsForVisibleItems(), obviously.

Comment: I merged my sample with yours. If you have one section it should be easy to adapt

Comment: This unfortunately leads to 1) Only removing the elements which are visible. And 2) to a crash because the invisible IndexPaths are nil. - With "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'"

Comment: The mistake is basing your logic around the cells. Your logic should resolve around the dataSource array. Do you see the diffrence?

Answer (score 0):

This did the job. But without animation though:

```
    for ( cellID, _ ) in cellIdToFeedItem_ToDelete
    {
        if let index = feedItemsActive_.firstIndex( where: {
            (i) -> Bool in
            i.id == cellID
        } )
        {
            feedItemsActive_.remove( at: index )
        }
    }

    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

Comment: If you want the animation, don't use `reloadData`. Use `deleteItems(at:)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the initial question. But it does not work. So how do I retrieve ALL indexPaths?